# Explanation of left and right side of statement when creating new class instance

Tags: c#

I have a class

```
public class Table
{
    public string color {get; set;}
    public string height {get; set;}
}
```

When I want to create a new instance of this class I use:

```
//1.
var myTable = new Table();
```

or

```
//2.
Table myTable = new Table();
```

or

```
//3.
IEnumerable<Table> Tables = new List<Table>();
```

but not

```
//4.
List<Table> y = new IEnumerable<Table>();
```

Can somebody explain what the left side (var / Table / IEnumerable) is doing and what the right side (new Table / new List() etc) in contrast is doing.

Why are they the same sometimes (eg 2) and different at other times (eg 3).

What's the difference between these three:

```
var Tables = new List<Table>();
List<Table> Tables = new List<Table>();
IEnumerable<Table> Tables = new List<Table>();
```

I know this is basic stuff, but I have not found a clear explanation of what the left and right-hand side of the statement means when creating an instance of a class in C# - online.

thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left side specifies the type of the variable. Just like in `int i;`, the word `int` says that `i` is an integer. And `var` means that you are too lazy to write the type name and you want to compiler to guess the type you want to use.

That's the easy part.

The right side is a value that you assign to the variable. Just like in `int i = 10;`, `10` is stored in `i`, in

```
Table myTable = new Table();
```

the value of `new Table()` is stored in `myTable`.

And what does `new Table()` do? Well, it simply creates a new instance of `Table`.

This is easy as well.

In other words, all your are doing is creating a new instance of `Table` and putting it into a variable called `myTable`. It's just like:

```
int i = 1 + 1;
```

You create a new integer 2 by adding 1 to 1, then you assign the result to `i`.

> why can the two sides be different?

Just like in `int i = 1 + 1;`, the right side doesn't need to be the same as the left side (and sometimes they must be different). Since all you're doing here is assigning a value to a variable, as long as the right side's value can be put into the variable on the left, it's fine!

Now here comes the hard part.

> Why does this work?

```
IEnumerable<Table> Tables = new List<Table>();
```

Because an instance of `List<Table>` can be put into an instance of `IEnumerable<Table>`. It's that simple!

> why can an instance of `List<Table>` be put into an instance of `IEnumerable<Table>`?

Because `List<T>` implements the interface `IEnumerable<T>`. Therefore, a `List<T>` has all the methods in `IEnumerable<T>`.

> Why doesn't this work?

```
List<Table> y = new IEnumerable<Table>();
```

Because first, you cannot create an instance of an interface by `new XXX()`. You should learn more about how interfaces work in C#. Second, an object whose type is `IEnumerable<T>` is not compatible with `List<T>`.

Still don't understand why an object whose type is `IEnumerable<T>` is not compatible with `List<T>`?

You're basically doing this:

```
int i = 1.234;
```

`double` and `int` just don't go together!

Comment: Good explanation thanks. Is this correct... you said "an instance of List<Table> can be put into an instance of IEnumerable<Table>. It's that simple!" - You can't create an instance of an IEnumerable<> interface though?!

Comment: @niico no it's not a typo. You indeed cannot create an instance of IEnumerable<T>, but you *can* create a variable that is of type IEnumerable<T>. The purpose of this is mainly to provide flexibility since you can assign anything to the variable as long as it *implements* the interface. And example of such a class is List<T>

Comment: So effectively IEnumerable is a subset of List - IEnumerable has (because List inherits from it) all the capabilities (methods and properties) of IEnumerable. But IEnumerable doesn't have all the capabilities of List - in a Venn diagram IEnumerable sits fully inside List?

Comment: so LEFT = VARIABLE. RIGHT = INSTANCE? Left is the variable that references the instance of the class on the right? < this is the key to what I wasn't making explicit in my head I think.

Comment: @niico  that's right. That is exactly why the fourth piece of code doesn't work.

Comment: Are you prevented from, say, referencing an instance of an IEnumerable<MyObj> object with a variable of type List<MyObj> - because the user may call, say, a method on List which doesn't exist in IEnumerable - causing a runtime error? Is that the logic?

Comment: (though IEnumerale is an interface - so I should say - creating an instance of an object that IMPLEMENTS IEnumerable - rather than create an instance of IEnumerable)?!

Comment: Yes, technically that's the correct wording. @niico

Comment: If you think my answer helped you, please consider accepting it! @niico

Answer (score 1):

**In short**

Right hand side creates the actual object, left hand side creates a reference to the object.

**Long version**

Right hand side creates the actual object there is no mystery here I guess. You cannot do `new IEnumerable<Table>()` because `IEnumerable` is an interface, not a class. You can only create objects from classes.

Then you need to assign this object to a certain reference and declare the type of the reference.

```
List<Table> Tables = new List<Table>();
```

This is straightforward, your reference has the same type with your object.

```
IEnumerable<Table> Tables = new List<Table>();
```

This involves inheritance of classes. If you go to the source code of class `List` you will see `List` implement interface `IEnumerable`. Thus when defining references you can use implemented interface and extended classes instead of the real class name.

This has some additional benefits, such that you can assign objects from other classes that implement `IEnumerable<Table>` to `Tables`.

```
var Tables = new List<Table>();
```

This style has been around only recently. Basically if you do not bother to give any type to the reference, the compiler can deduce one for you. If you mouse over to `var` you'll see the inferred type. If you don't find the deduced type suitable, you can always write the type yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In all cases you are instantiating your Table class. The most basic instantiation is case 2:

```
Table myTable = new Table();
```

You are essentially saying, give me an instance of the Table class called myTable to work with locally.

In case 1, where you use the var keyword, you are doing the same thing, except myTable is implicitly typed. The compiler decides what type myTable should be. It is still an instance of your Table class, and is still strongly typed.

`List<T>` implements the interface `IEnumerable<T>`. All `List<T>'s` are `IEnumerable<T>'s`, and can be instantiated as such, like you do in case 3. When instantiating this way, you do not have access to the methods specific to the `IList<T>` interface, and can only access methods of the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

Case 4 will not work for at least a couple of reasons. First, you cannot instantiate an interface. Second, even if you could, not all `IEnumerable<T>'s` are `List<T>'s`. Read up on Inheritance and you'll start to understand this case.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, not all `IEnumerable<T>`'s are `List<T>`'s. An relevant example will make it clear.

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = new int[5];
List<int> intsList = ints; //does not compile!
```

An array of ints is not the same as a List of ints even though they both implement `IEnumerable`. Even more obvious is the Dictionary. Clearly a Dictionary has different methods and properties than a List:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyvals = new Dictionary<string,string>();
List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> keyvalList = keyvals; //does not compile!
```

You see, when you do this:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyvals = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

you lose Dictionary specific features. You cannot, for instance, do:

```
keyvals.ContainsKey("foo");
```

`IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` does not define a `ContainsKey` method. In fact, basically all `IEnumerable<T>` does is expose `GetEnumerator()` and some extension methods.

But `IEnumerable<T>` can still be very useful. Consider [this LinqPad script](http://share.linqpad.net/vph6s4.linq) that defines a generic method that receives an `IEnumerable<Table>`. You can send it an array of Table or a List of Table or a Stack of Table, etc.,  and it will still work:

```
void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<SomeTable> arrayOfSomeTable = 
        new SomeTable[] { new SomeTable(), new SomeTable() };

    IEnumerable<SomeTable> listOfSomeTable = 
        new List<SomeTable> { new SomeTable(), new SomeTable() };

    Stack<SomeOtherTable> stackOfOtherTable = new Stack<SomeOtherTable>();
    stackOfOtherTable.Push(new SomeOtherTable());
    stackOfOtherTable.Push(new SomeOtherTable());
    IEnumerable<SomeOtherTable> stackOtherTable = stackOfOtherTable;

    ShowTableDef(arrayOfSomeTable);
    ShowTableDef(listOfSomeTable);
    ShowTableDef(stackOfOtherTable);
}

public void ShowTableDef<T>(IEnumerable<T> objectToLog) where T : ITable
{
    foreach (ITable tbl in objectToLog)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tbl.GetTableDefinition());
    }
}

public interface ITable { string GetTableDefinition(); }

public class SomeTable : ITable
{
    public string GetTableDefinition() { return "foo"; }
}

public class SomeOtherTable : ITable
{
    public string GetTableDefinition() { return "bar"; }
}
```

Comment: thx - is the reason this does not compile: List<int> intsList = ints; //does not compile! - essentially because List has methods ints does not have (effectively a superset) - the user may call one and cause a runtime error?

Comment: Well, basically yes. The compiler says there is no implicit conversion available. An implicit conversion is one the compiler won't complain about because it knows no data loss will occur. Let's be clear this is in no way restricted to just List<T>. You can use an explicit cast `(List<int>)ints[]`, and get a runtime error instead of a compile time error because you are effectively telling the compiler you know it is safe (but it isn't).